# Android Tablet Layout based on density and resolution -sw533-land

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I need to create a different layout for tablet screens.

To ensure all tablet excluding any larger screen phone will use the new layout, how should I name my layout folder? Is it correct if I name my folder layout-sw533-land? Is there a syntax that target tablet only?

Comment: [Android developer resources](https://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html) suggests using sw600dp for 7" tablets, and sw720dp for 10" tablets

Comment: But can you tell me why? sw600 is actually stand for shortest width 600dp, but a lot of large phones has got dp higher than that.

Comment: phones have a higher dpI than that, DP is a pseudo-pixel size that Google uses to ensure the same size object looks physically the same size on different screen sizes -- so a 100dp square should appear to be a 7mm square on any device (for example)

Comment: Thanks, Just created folder, layout-sw600dp. Finger crossed. Hope no phones will ever use that layout because it suppose to be for tablet only.

Comment: best way to make sure is to run tests on devices you think will be problematic